# Why is my PHP code inputting "0"s and no input for the other fields?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to create an INSERT to add data to the database using a form, but it's set "0000-00-00" for the date, and "0" for the other integers/floats, and there is no value for the VARCHARs.

```
<form action = "display.php" method = "post">
             <h3> Add a Product </h3>
             <input type = "text" id = "product_number" name = "product_number" cols=75 minlength="4" maxlength="4" placeholder = "Product Number" required>
             <br>
             <input type = "text" id = "supplier_id" name = "supplier_id" cols=75 minlength="4" maxlength="4" placeholder = "Supplier ID">
             <br>
             <input type = "text" id = "date" name = "date" cols=75 placeholder = "yyyy-mm-dd">
             <br>
             <input type = "number" id = "quantity" name = "quantity" cols=75 placeholder = "Quantity">
             <br>
             <input type = "text" id = "description" name = "description" cols=75 maxlength="50" placeholder = "Description">
             <br>
             <input type = "text" id = "price" name = "price" cols=75 placeholder = "Price">
             <br>
             <button type = "submit" name = "submit" cols=75 value = "Add"> Add Product to Database </button>
         </form>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<?php


 $product_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_number']);
 $supplier_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['supplier_id']);
 $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
 $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['quantity']);
 $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
 $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);

 $sql = "INSERT into products (product_number, supplier_id, date, quantity, description, price) values ('$product_number', '$supplier_id', '$date', '$quantity', '$description', '$price')";


 if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "";
 } else {
     echo ""; 
 }
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please use text instead image of your code.

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the code that I am struggling with. The database works, but it's inputting "0"s instead of the values I am trying to add using the form.

Comment: I am not sure I got your problem but I suggest you should change the input of date from text to date (type = "text" --> type="date") this will help you with the date format and you will avoid some problems in the next steps

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that your INSERT statement is running even before you submit the form.

Wrap the code in a statement which checks if the request is a POST request or not (the browser will only generate a POST - instead of a GET) when a form is submitted.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
 $product_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_number']);
 $supplier_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['supplier_id']);
 $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
 $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['quantity']);
 $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);
 $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);

 $sql = "INSERT into products (product_number, supplier_id, date, quantity, description, price) values ('$product_number', '$supplier_id', '$date', '$quantity', '$description', '$price')";


 if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
     echo "";
 } else {
     echo ""; 
 }
 mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

P.S. I suspect you probably also get a second, correct, row inserted after you've submitted the form? There aren't any obvious issues with the code apart from that (although it would be preferable to use prepared statements and parameters, instead of escaping the strings and concatenating the values into the SQL - [this article](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) (among many) shows you how to write your queries in the safest way)).